# MERN Stack - onClick function used on table row to submit data - Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, function, button, onclick, mern

I am new here and relatively new to programming.
A bit of background... I have created a song list called from MongoDB which renders in a table such as

```
<table className="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Song Title</th>
        <th>Album</th>
        <th>Vote</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      { this.songList() }     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The songList() is called by mapping the songList Method which keeps the song list up to date after editing and deleting entries.

Now for the bit I cannot work out...

```
const Song = props => (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.song.songTitle}</td>
      <td>{props.song.album}</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/"+ props.song._id}>edit</Link> | <a href="#" onClick={() => { 
        props.deleteSong(props.song._id) }}>delete</a>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button style={{ //irrelevant }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >Choose Song</button>
      </td>
    </tr   )
```

What I want these buttons to do is to store the amount of clicks relating to votes for each song which can then be used to pick a favourite song however I am not sure how to achieve this.

Could someone point me in the right direction on what is best practice for this or if doing it this way is even possible. Like I say, I am a newbie so please explain if I am way off the mark.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to achieve this is to have a `score` property in the MongoDB `Song` model. It will store the song's total number of upvotes - total number of downvotes.

Think about it as a question on Stack Overflow:

- Make the defaultValue = 0
- Create 2 functions in your client side: upvote(songId) downvote(singId)
- upvote(songId) sends a put request to your `/songs/:id/upvote`. The server needs to update the `song` document by incrementing its `score`.
- downvote(songId) sends a put request to your `/songs/:id/downvote`. The server needs to update the `song` document by decrementing its `score`.
- In your interface, render the score of the song next to the downvote and upvote buttons.